# Spring-JPA-Hibernate Configuration: setting property hiberate.hbm2dll.auto to create has no effect?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, configuration

I have this configuration problem:

1) I have jpaPropertyMap with property hibernate.hbm2dll.auto set to create but it has no effect. Its not creating table generation SQL.

I can see in log file other jpaPropertyMap property like dialect getting properly set so property map is being read.

2) If i set HibernateJpaVendorAdapter's property generateddl to true, table is being generated.

so why does hibernate.hbm2dll.auto not working in the case/generating tables.

Here is the Configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.demoapps.placementwebsite"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cpm?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2dll.auto" value="create"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

Using:
Hibernate 4.2.2.Final
Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 5):

The property is `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`, and not `hibernate.hbm2dll.auto`.

DDL = Data Definition Language

DLL = Dynamic-Link Library